# Freelance websites that doesn't require credit card?

Tags: payment-terms, payments

I want to start freelancing online but only have a bank account from a bank that isn't international. Is there any solution besides changing bank or getting a credit card(what is also a requirement for a PayPal account)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author needs to get that information from whatever web sites, including Paypal, he or she is using.

RTFM.

Comment: Depending on whether or not you are currently freelancing, you may want to consider not _changing_ banks, but _creating_ a new international bank account solely for freelancing work.

Comment: I don't see how this question is off topic, I'm asking about freelancing websites, which are a part of freelancing. It seems like you don't want to advertise websites here, but i see that being done all the time. I don't see how a beginner asking where to start is a illegitimate and off topic question.

Comment: @Conflux, are you against having a PayPal account? I'd suggest keeping your current bank account and opening a PP account - it'll still be tied to your bank account but you can send and receive money from (pretty much) anywhere.

Comment: I would love to have a PayPal account, but it is requiring credit card nowadays, that is the point of the question, I don't have a credit card and i don't want one.

Comment: @Conflux debit cards are different to credit cards - you can register with Paypal and use your debit card (VISA, Mastercard, etc.). That said, I'm assuming you have a debit card, I realise not all banks and building societies offer them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which country you are in.

Unless your bank is subject to an embargo, all banks worldwide are linked through the SWIFT system and can handle international transactions. Do be aware of potentially high fees - sometimes for that reason, it is worth getting a bank account in another country.

For Web sites that want a credit card, you can usually use either a debit card linked to your bank account. Since you don't want a credit card, you probably also don't want a debit card.

In that case, you can get a prepaid credit card.